# Import TextView in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with importing TextView it was working perfectly but suddenly it shows an error, and App is not working at all.

My project contains 4 Fragments and in one of them, there is PHP with DB connection to get some data and display it in TextView. here is my code plz look and help me to solve it.

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView txtName;  // lastname
    private TextView txtfName; // firstname
    private TextView txtEmail;
```

and here to findviewById

```
@Override
  public View onCreateView(
      LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    txtName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);   //to get lastname
    txtfName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fname); //firstname
    txtEmail = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.email); //email
```

here to get data in TextView

```
txtfName.setText(firstname + " "+ lastname); //firstname
txtname.setText(lastname); //lastname
```

and here is the XML layout example

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Name"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: what does this have to do with php ? please remove unnecessary tags

Comment: I am working with it to connect my app with MySQL to allow user login and display all the information directly from db.

Comment: but you've included no php code here, so again, i don't see how it is relevant to your question

Answer (score 0):

In the Java file, if you point your mouse to the red lines on the right side of the editor you can import any classes missing like in this image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMcX4.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: not working, I import all classes in layout XML  <TextView or <EditText it shows error in red color "Cannot resolve class EditText "

Answer (score 0):

Place this at the top of your code (After the package stuff):

```
import android.widget.TextView;
```

I only answered by how I carefully understood the question and your screenshots, if this is not what you are expecting, clarify the question.

Comment: If you encounter a problem like that again, do a search like this:
"import MISSING CLASS"
example:
"import TextView"
Just search it on google or wherever, you'll get a straightforward answer!

Comment: no it's not solved my problem even I create a new project which contains textview it will display an error I don't know maybe the problem with SDK or version.

Comment: @user2648424 If you're using Android Studios, I'm gonna tell you this: That happens a lot of the times you're using it. Just rebuild, if not search for tutorials on how to fix specific issues, can't help you with that since it's only you that know the specifics of everything.

Comment: Another thing, please take a screenshot of the whole xml document so that we may inspect it.

Comment: And another thing, please take a screenshot of the top portion of your Java file, I'm sensing that you did something terribly wrong on both files.